# Are tags without wikis/infos still valid?

Tags: support, tags

We can find all the tags used at SO here : https://stackoverflow.com/tags

Most of the tags are available with details (Tag info) about them, like in this example:

> [image]

But some tags dont have any explanation.  Here's an example from https://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1278&tab=popular :

> [image]

**Are tags without wikis/infos still valid?**

Comment: Correct tag name is **`spring-webflow-2`** not just **`webflow2`**

Comment: thank you @Abdulla but they were showing in tags ,could not find the filter for correct name

Comment: correct name means?? i didnt get you

Comment: but usually we have info regarding every tags in that section , so do you mean to say that webflow2 is not a valid tag ? or was that a valid one without any info ?

Answer (score 1):

There is no tag [webflow2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/webflow2). The correct tag is [spring-webflow-2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/spring-webflow-2).

[spring-webflow-2](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/29219)

[image: 01]

You can create a new tag by adding it to a relevant question, then you can provide a wiki and an excerpt for the tag. You have under 20k rep, so your edit will be in the review queue until it gets 5 accept votes by other users.

[image: 02]

Comment: 4th column , 4 item : http://stackoverflow.com/tags?page=1278&tab=popular

Comment: @utility this means some one just created tag. SO it shows as created, If you are work with that tag you can add info as well

Comment: ohh kk i thought info is mandatory to create / add new tag .. thank you @abdulla ..also why does that not showing in your search ? ..yes they were synonymns

Comment: @utility happy to share knowledge.

Comment: need info and use that higher. if you just type webflow and keep space it will load. if you use this in frequently it will show it as well

Comment: yes..got it :) ..

Comment: @utility happy to help :)